# Write a program to read first 5 even numbers in an empty tuple and join any another tuple with it, then find the length of a tuple

Tags: python

Write a Python program to read first 5 even numbers in an empty tuple and join any another tuple with it, then find the length of a tuple.
Final output will be like (2,4,6,8,10,5,13,24)
Length is 8

```
t1=()
even=(2,4,6,8,10)
t1=int(input('enter first 5 even number : '))
if t1==even:
  t=tuple(t1)
else:
  print('please enter first 5 even number : ')
t2=(3,6,4,9)
tf=t+t2
print(f"length of final tuple is {len(tf)}")
```

error-

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-027ac63599bb> in <module>()
     10   print('please enter first 5 enven number : ')
     11 t2=(3,6,4,9)
---> 12 tf=t+t2
     13 print(f"length of final tuple is {len(tf)}")

NameError: name 't' is not defined
```

Comment: Edit the question to show the code correctly indented.

Comment: what did you assign to `t1`? `if t1==even:`  if this is false, this `t=tuple(t1)` never happens

Comment: If not "t1==even" then "t" is not set but used later and "t1" is set to a single int which can't be equal to a tuple.

Comment: Why do you have `t1=()` at the start? Then reassign `t1` later? Did you meant that as `t=()`?

Answer (score 0):

You defined the variable t only inside if statement:

```
if t1==even:
    t=tuple(t1)
```

If this condition evaluated to false then the variable t will not be declared and you had used it in another place inside the program.
What do you want program to do if the condition is false?!
One solution is to define an empty tuple in the else, then your code will be:

```
if t1==even:
    t=tuple(t1)
else:
    t=()
    // here complete your code
```

Or you can declare it in the first as empty tuple and then using it when you want.

Answer (score 0):

#### Errors:-

- `t1=int(input())` t1 is `int` and even is `tuple` so, `if t1==even:` can never be true.
- `t=tuple(t1)` is defined ***only*** inside `if condition` so `NameError: name 't' is not defined` is raised.

#### Code:-

```py
t=()
even=(2,4,6,8,10)
t1=input('Enter first 5 even numbers: ')
t1=tuple(map(int,t1.split(',')))
if t1 == even:
  t=tuple(t1)
else:
  print('You didn\'t enter first 5 even numbers!')
t2=(3,6,4,9)
tf=t+t2
print(f"length of final tuple is {len(tf)}")
```

#### Output:-

```
Enter first 5 even numbers: 2,4,6,8,10
length of final tuple is 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You define `t1` as an `int`:

```
t1=int(input('enter first 5 even number : '))
```

In that light, `t1==even` is never `True`.

Further, looking at your code, if the `if` statement is not `True` (Which it will never be because of the above), then the variable `t` is never declared.

Hence, when you call `tf=t+t2`, `t` is not declared and it raises an error.
**Two Things to fix:**

1. I believe you mean to do `if t1 in even:`
2. make a default definition for `t` before the `if` block or like wise indent the part after the `else` block into the `else` block

Answer (score 0):

First of all: even if the first part of the program was correct, how can you get as final output `(2,4,6,8,10,5,13,24)` if the tuple `t2` you join is `(3,6,4,9)`?

Leaving that aside:

- How does the input statement expects the numbers to be entered? Space separated? If so, note that the input is a string, a trying to parse `int("2 4 6 8 10")` will result in a `ValueError`!
- Would it be more logical - given the error message you print in the `else` statement - to keep asking for the input until is correct?

In code, I would write something along the following lines:

```
t1 = ()
t2 = (5, 13, 14)

while t1 != (2, 4, 6, 8, 10):
    i = input("enter first 5 even numbers (space separated) : ")
    t1 = tuple([int(x) for x in i.split(" ")])

tf = t1 + t2    
print(f"length of final tuple is {len(tf)}")
```